# How to write an LLVM pass?

Tags: llvm

I am writing an LLVM pass, just following http://llvm.org/docs/WritingAnLLVMPass.html#basic-code-required.

I have finished the `Makefile`, the `source code`, however, when I came to do the `make`:

`Now that it’s all together, compile the file with a simple “gmake” command in the local directory and you should get a new file “Debug+Asserts/lib/Hello.so” under the top level directory of the LLVM source tree (not in the local directory).`

It reported

`../../../Makefile.common:61: ../../../Makefile.config: No such file or directory
../../../Makefile.common:69: /Makefile.rules: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target '/Makefile.rules'.  Stop.`

I didn't change the any configuration files in the root directory. There is no `Makefile.config` in my root directory, but there is a file called `Makefile.config.in`. `Makefile.common` appears in the root directory.

Comment: Just so you know, requests for tutorials/examples/libraries/websites/APIs are specifically off-topic here. Can you amend the question to show a specific problem you are stuck on instead?

Answer (score 4):

I hate to be the one to tell you, but I think you'll need to get your basics straight before diving into compiler development:

- http://llvm.org/docs/WritingAnLLVMPass.html has a lot of documentation that you should definitely read, including information on the Manager:

> The PassManager class takes a list of passes, ensures their prerequisites are set up correctly, and then schedules passes to run efficiently. All of the LLVM tools that run passes use the PassManager for execution of these passes.

- A makefile is a mechanism of defining how a piece of software is built by compiler, linker, installation scripts etc. How that will look like depends completely on how you plan to implement your software. In your case, you should definitely orientate yourself on existing passes. In fact, http://llvm.org/docs/WritingAnLLVMPass.html#setting-up-the-build-environment has a rather detailed explanation on how to set up the makefile, including a template, which is really simple

  ```
  # Makefile for hello pass
  # Path to top level of LLVM hierarchy
  LEVEL = ../../..    
  # Name of the library to build
  LIBRARYNAME = Hello    
  # Make the shared library become a loadable module so the tools can
  # dlopen/dlsym on the resulting library.
  LOADABLE_MODULE = 1
  # Include the makefile implementation stuff
  include $(LEVEL)/Makefile.common
  ```

If you don't understand that, you'll have to read a bit of existing Makefiles or make documentation.

All in all, I think writing LLVM passes might not be the thing I'd get started with if not being used to these kind of standard tools, but I recommend just diving into the LLVM source code tree to get a feeling. Practice makes a master!

Comment: Thank you. I first tried to do `make` in the llvm/lib/Transformations/Hello, but it reported ../../Makefile.config not found

Comment: ^ @xwang: please edit that into your question, adding more detail as necessary. That will make the question more on-topic here.